# Null value returned whenever I try and cast string to DecimalType in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

It's been a while, but I'm back yet again..

**The Problem:**
When I try and convert any column of type StringType using PySpark to DecimalType (and FloatType), what's returned is a null value.  Methods like `F.substring` still work on the column, so it's obviously still being treated like a string, even though I'm doing all I can to point it in the right direction.

**Replication**:
Example csv:

```
Currency,Total
USD,"3,472.43"
```

Example .py file:

```
from pyspark.sql import DataFrame, SparkSession, types, functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StringType, DoubleType, TimestampType

def transform():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(
        "Example for StackOverflow").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()

    raw_df = spark.read.csv('ex.csv', header=True)

    processed_df = \
        raw_df.withColumn('Amount2', F.col('Total').cast(types.DecimalType()))

    processed_df.show()

    processed_df = \
        raw_df.withColumn('Amount3',  F.substring(F.col('Total'), 0, 4))

    processed_df.show()

    processed_df = \
        raw_df.withColumn('Amount2', F.col('Total').cast(types.DecimalType()))

    processed_df.show()

transform()
```

When ran, gives the following output:

```
+--------+--------+-------+
|Currency|   Total|Amount2|
+--------+--------+-------+
|     USD|3,472.43|   null|
+--------+--------+-------+

+--------+--------+-------+
|Currency|   Total|Amount3|
+--------+--------+-------+
|     USD|3,472.43|   3,47|
+--------+--------+-------+

+--------+--------+-------+
|Currency|   Total|Amount2|
+--------+--------+-------+
|     USD|3,472.43|   null|
+--------+--------+-------+
```

Not really understanding where the wires are getting crossed here.

**Attempted solutions**:
I've tried just about everything I can think of - using a `StructType` (which turned *everything* null), using various types (DecimalType, FloatType, etc.), changing inferSchema from true to false then back again, and of course, casting it.  Pretty sure this shouldn't be so difficult - so where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the comma is causing the trouble. After you load the data `raw_df`, you can replace the `,` in the amount:

```
processed_df = raw_df.withColumn('Amount2', F.regex_replace('Total',',',''))
```

Comment: I can't believe it, but it worked.  Should have tried this before assuming that Spark would infer an amount with commas.  Thank you so much!